# Kivy: how do I make a non-editable text input?

Tags: kivy, textinput

How to make a text input non editable by user ?

```
TextInput:
    id:out
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    foreground_color: (0, 1, 0, 1)
    multiline: True
    text:""
```

Comment: Set the **readonly** property to **True**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `readonly` property is your friend

```
TextInput:
    id:out
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    foreground_color: (0, 1, 0, 1)
    multiline: True
    text:""
    readonly: True
```

Comment: doing that does not even allows me to use arrow keys.How to allow atleast navigation?

Comment: @VisheshMangla - you can make a callback that for every change to the text, the text returns to your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `TextInput` field to disabled.

```
TextInput:
    id:out
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    foreground_color: (0, 1, 0, 1)
    multiline: True
    text:""
    disabled: True
```

check this answer for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45238685/7346913